# VB WPF Label Content Not Showing Math Calculation

Tags: string, vb.net, math, sum, feedback

Today I challenged myself to make a simple math application in a language I do not know (VB).
Coming from C# I thought it would be quick however I'm wrong to say the least.

What I'm trying to do is calculate the two values a user enters in real time in the inputAlpha and inputBeta text boxes and display the Sum/Difference/Average/etc in the respective label boxes to the right of the labels you do see.  At the moment I'm at an impass with two problems.  One is the sumOutput.Content is not showing the sum whether the local variable sum is a Integer or a String.  The second is the math isn't actually adding 10+10 rather it is just combining the two to 1010.  I understand this is probably trivial to 99% of you but I'm here to learn from my mistakes so I thank you for any feedback.

[image: Learning VB Math]

Comment: As a side note to the excellent answer below, the more "typical" usage with WPF is to use data binding instead of directly manipulating the controls.  You would assign your result to a property and raise a `PropertyChanged` event, and the control would be set up in xaml to take its value from the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue:

This wouldn't work properly in C#, either.

In VB, like C#, the `+` operator does double-duty. It can either perform math or concatenate strings. Since you are using the `Text` property on both sides, you have `String + String` which will concatenate the strings. If you want to do math, you need to convert the values to numbers first. For example, you could:

```
Dim left As Integer = Integer.Parse(inputAlphaTextBox.Text)
Dim right As Integer = Integer.Parse(inputBetaTextBox.Text)
Dim sum As Integer = left + right
```

Second issue:

VB doesn't have a separate assignment operator (`=`) and equality operator (`==`) like C# does. It uses the symbol `=` for both assignment and equality and uses context to decide which one it needs.

Since you are using `Return`, it assumes there is an expression on the right-hand side. That expression is `sumOutput.Content = sum.ToString()`. Since it is expecting an expression, when it decides how to interpret the `=` operator, it chooses equality. So it's trying to return `True` or `False`.

This is where it gets weird and I'm making a little bit of a guess.

Your function returns `Integer`, but that's a `Boolean`. So why aren't you getting a compile error? I'm going to take a wild guess and assume you haven't changed the defaults, so `Option Strict` is off. This allows VB to make some type conversions that you might not expect. IIRC, `False` will convert to the integer `0` and `True` will convert to the Integer `1`.

This code, as written, would be poor practice even in C#. It should really be written like:

```
Private Sub DoMath()
    Dim left As Integer = Integer.Parse(inputAlphaTextBox.Text)
    Dim right As Integer = Integer.Parse(inputBetaTextBox.Text)
    Dim sum As Integer = left + right
    
    subOutput.Content = sum.ToString()
End Sub
```

There's nothing to return and the call site doesn't expect one, so it should have no return value. In C# that's a `void` function, in VB that's a `Sub`. Removing the `Return` statement helps VB understand you want to perform an assignment, not make a comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation.  Consider my quest for knowledge expanded and my eyes opened regarding why what I did was wrong.